# Is there some local code that can substitute Facebook's Like button code?

Tags: facebook, html, pagespeed

I have on my website the Twitter Tweet and Facebook Like buttons, configured on their developer websites. They generate about 7 times more bytes (in scripts, images and iframes) for downloading than my actual site does.

When I analyse pages with, e.g. [**Google Pagespeed**](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), [**Pingdomcome**](http://tools.pingdom.com/) or [**Webpagetest**](http://www.webpagetest.org/), the main complaints are about redirects, render-blocking JavaScript, and uncompressed/uncachable resources, and they all originate from Twitter and Facebook (and some from Google, e.g. jquery).

I found this can serve as a bare-bones replacement for the Twitter button code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=MyGreatExample&url=http://www.example.com"></a>
```

But I have no Facebook replacement, and no idea what Google search term would find one. Displaying the number of "Likes" is not necessary.

**Update:** found this: http://simplesharingbuttons.com/ Question answered.